# How to make selectionColor prop in TextInput transparent?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to customize my cursor and selection color for a TextInput. On iOS, changing the color will work fine and the selected color will appear lighter and easy to read through. On Android however, the color is coming through exactly as it is written, which is a huge problem considering my text is black as well as my selection color.

I could easily just use a ternary operation and change it between iOS and Android, however I need the cursor color to be the same and it is using the given color for both of them. An alternative may also be to change the text color when it is selected, however selected text doesn't appear to be a state of which I can work with.

```
<TextInput
  selectionColor='#000000'
/>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWjt7.jpg

The top image is what I want and is what happens on iOS. The bottom image is what I'm getting on Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly pass a color with an alpha value for Android to make it transparent.

If you set your selectionColor using a rgba color then you should get the result that you want.

`selectionColor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'`

[image: selection highlighted in android]

You can read more about the different colors that react-native can handle and their options here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/colors

Comment: Will this alpha code not affect the cursor though? I want that without any transparency if possible. I'm getting the color through platform and definitely don't want the alpha color everywhere, but still want it to match everything else if this is changed.

Comment: Well as far as I know this is the only way to do it. I don’t think it affects the cursor but if it does that’s a trade off you’ll have to decide on.

Comment: Hmm. This seems to be changing the color of the TextInput too, not just when it's highlighted. https://imgur.com/g4wZ2rP I'm having trouble finding a prop that would be able to handle the text color without affected the rest of it.

Comment: Sounds like there is an issue with the component if the selectionColor is affecting the text color.

Comment: Got it working. Other elements were using the same focused color somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to set the color at build time (which was my case), you can have a different cursor and selection color on Android.

In `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`, add the following items to your app's theme :

```xml
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/highlight</item>
```

Then in `android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml`, set your colors :

```xml
<color name="accent">#ff0000</color> <!-- will be used for cursor color -->
<color name="highlight">#66ff0000</color> <!-- will be used for highlight color, notice the 66 at the beginning which is the alpha value -->
```

Finally, conditionally exclude the `selectionColor` prop on Android :

```js
<TextInput
  selectionColor={Platform.OS !== 'android' ? '#ff0000' : undefined}
/>
```